# EasyPhp Is not executing my jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, easyphp, localserver

I'm trying to realize a simple web-chat.
The main php file is done, which should send messages and then get them back using jquery and ajax. It's working (more or less) but there's a problem.

If I save it as an html file and double-click it the jquery works (ajax doesn't because it needs the php) BUT when I try to open it inside the EasyPHP application (Local server), jquery doesn't work anymore - both if I save the file as php or html.

This is how I'm trying to implement my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery\jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

This is part of the code which is not working in EasyPHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() { 

        $('#chat').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode==13)
            $('#send').click();
        });

        $('#send').click(function() {
            var dt = new Date();
            var msg= $('#chat').val() + ';' + dt.getHours()+':' + dt.getMinutes();

            $('#chat').val("");
            $('#convers').append(msg + "\n");

            $.post("chat.php", 
                { name: "nickname", messaggio: msg },
                function(data,status) {
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\n Status: " + status);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Did you open the browser console and check for errors? Note that URL's in a windows enviroment are case sensitive